# Remove file from existing commit in Sublime Merge

Tags: git, git-commit, git-revert, sublimemerge

How to remove specific file from existing commit (the last commit in a branch) in Sublime Merge?

Comment: Is sublime merge the right tool for doing this?

Comment: If it's the last commit that you want to modify, delete the file, commit the delete, and squash the two commits into one, or delete the file, stage the deletion, and then amend the last commit by picking that option from the action dropdown (arrow next to the commit button). For anything else, just like in git you would need to edit the appropriate commit and all that follows after it; definitely doable but not a fun task in either case